# I'm getting a service error when I run eb init in my terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting a service error when I run eb init that says "ServiceError- 'express' not a valid key=value pair..."
Someone please help me out! What should I do in order for it to run properly?

Comment: Can you provide more info, on exactly what are you ding, full error messages.

Comment: I ran eb init after installing eb on my terminal, and it gave the error message that I stated, along with some random numbers. Can you tell me what's wrong with that?

Comment: Copy the _exact_ text from your terminal (excepting any passwords or account numbers), and paste it into your question as a code block. If you've made any configuration changes, post the configuration files as well. As written, all anybody can do is guess at an answer.